# Accessing bit in byte[,,]

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, hash, 3d, byte

I am making a data structure, lets call it a bit cube. The purpuse is to save space over a bool[,,] but have the same type of operations.

As of now, I can set a bit and see if a bit is set like this:

```
public class BitCube {
    private byte[,,] data;

    public BitCube(int size) {
        data = new byte[size, size, size];
    }

    public void SetBit(int x, int y, int z, int n) {
        data[x, y, z] |= (byte)(1 << n);
    }

    private bool GetBit(int x, int y, int z, int n) {
        return (data[x, y, z] & (1 << n)) >= 1;
    }
}
```

This works. Unfortunately these operations does not resemble the ones of  `bool[,,]`. From the users perspective `bool[,,]` and `BitCube` should not differ in their operations.

What I want to do is to not take parameter `n` and instead calculate the position of the bit using `x`, `y`, `z`.

`BitCube` would look something like this:

```
public class BitCube {
    private byte[,,] data;

    public BitCube(int size) {
        if (size % 8 != 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Size must to be divisable by 8");
        }
        data = new byte[size / 8, size / 8, size / 8];
    }

    public bool this[int x, int y, int z] {
        get {
            return GetBit(x, y, z);
        }
    }

    public void SetBit(int x, int y, int z) {
        int n = (x + y + z) % 8;
        if (x != 0) x /= 8;
        if (y != 0) y /= 8;
        if (z != 0) z /= 8;
        data[x, y, z] |= (byte)(1 << n);
    }

    private bool GetBit(int x, int y, int z) {
        int n = (x + y + z) % 8;
        if (x != 0) x /= 8;
        if (y != 0) y /= 8;
        if (z != 0) z /= 8;
        return (data[x, y, z] & (1 << n)) >= 1;
    }
}
```

Calculating the index of the sought byte is easy. The problem I have is calulating the index `n` of the bit. I realize that I have to use some kind of hash function. I am not very familiar with those and as I start to investigate I'm getting the feeling that what I am trying to do is not possible. Because of the small range of the bit index (0, 8). I thought I'd ask here before going down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8 bits constituting a byte can be viewed as a small 2x2x2 bit-cube. To access each bit, *double* the range each index, and use the last bit of each index as the "sub-index" into each mini bit-cube / byte:

```
public BitCube(int size)
{
    // new requirement
    if (size % 2 != 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Size must be even");
    }
    data = new byte[size / 2, size / 2, size / 2];
}

// calculate the index into the mini byte-cubes
private static int bytecubeIndex(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return (x % 2) * 4 + (y % 2) * 2 + (z % 2);
}

public void SetBit(int x, int y, int z)
{
    data[x / 2, y / 2, z / 2] |= (byte)(1 << bytecubeIndex(x, y, z));
}

private bool GetBit(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return (data[x / 2, y / 2, z / 2] & 
            (byte)(1 << bytecubeIndex(x, y, z))) != 0;
}
```